# count the occurrences of all the letters in a string PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to count the frequency of occurrences of all the letters in a string. Say I have

```
$str = "cdcdcdcdeeeef";
```

I can use str_split and array_count_values to achieve this.

```
array_count_values(str_split($str));
```

Wondering if there is another way to do this without converting the string to an array? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to convert that into an `array()` you can use `substr_count()` to achieve the same.

> substr_count — Count the number of substring occurrences

```
<?php
$str = "cdcdcdcdeeeef";
echo substr_count($str, 'c'); 
?>
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

`substr_count()` returns the number of times the needle substring occurs in the haystack string. Please note that needle is case sensitive.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the misconception, you can use `count_chars` to have a counted value of each character in a string. An example:

```
<?php
$str = "cdcdcdcdeeeef";

foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $strr => $value) {
   echo chr($strr) . " occurred a number of $value times in the string." . "<br>";
}
?>
```

[PHP Manual: count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

> count_chars — Return information about characters used in a string

Comment: not the answer I'm looking for. I want to count all the occurrences of each letter in the string, not just a particular letter. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a php function that returns information about characters used in a string: `count_chars`

Well it might not be what you are looking for, because according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php it

> Counts the number of occurrences of every byte-value (0..255) in
>   string and returns it in various ways

Example from same link (http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php):

```
<?php
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Strings
{
    public function count_of_each_letter($string){
        $string_chars = array();
        $length_ = mb_strlen($string,'UTF-8');
        if($length_== 0){return null;}
        else{
            for ($i=0; $i < $length_; $i++) { 
                $each_letter = mb_substr($string,0,1,'UTF-8');
                $string_chars[$each_letter] = mb_substr_count($string, $each_letter);
                $string = str_replace($each_letter,"", $string);
                $length_ = mb_strlen($string,'UTF-8');          
            }
            $string = '';
            foreach ($string_chars as $key => $value) { 
                $string .= $key.'-'.$value.'<br>';
            }
            return $string;
        }
    }
}
$new_counter  = new Strings();
echo $new_counter::count_of_each_letter('ختواجرایآهنگبهصورتتکنفرهنمود.اوازسال۱۹۷۲تا۱۹۷۵،۴آلبوماستودیوییتک‌نفرهمنتشرکردوحتینامزدیکجایزهاسکارهمشد.درهمینسال‌هاگروهاقدامبهبرگزاریتورکنسرتدراروپاونیزیکتورجهانیکردند.جکسونفایودرسال۱۹۷۵ازشرکتنشرموسیقیموتاونرکوردزبهسی‌بی‌اسرکوردزنقلمکانکردند.گروههمچنانبهاجراهایبین‌المللیخودادامهمی‌دادواز۱۹۷۶تا۱۹۸۴(از۱۵تا۲۴سالگیمایکل)ششآلبوماستودیوییدیگرمنتشرکرد.درهمینمدت،مایکلترانه‌سرایاصلیگروهجکسونزبود.Cantional,oderGesangbuchAugsburgischerKonfessionin1627.ohannSebastianBachcomposedafour-partsetting,BWV285,whichiswithouttext.twaspublishedasNo.196inthecollectionofchoralesbyJohannPhilippKirnbergerundCarlPhilippEmanufread');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by following way as well:

```
$str = 'aabbbccccdddeeedfff';
$arr = str_split($str);
$result = array_count_values($arr);
$string = http_build_query($result,'','');
echo str_replace('=','',$string);
```

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to educate researchers.